# Web Server Installation Error (RHEL)

Tags: webserver, rhel

my friend has been trying to install web server via RHEL, but this error has pop out, can anybody explain why does this happens? Is it because of the firewall/ports has not been open or am i using the wrong command?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps.

Step 1: `yum install httpd -y`

This will install Apache

Step 2: `systemctl enable httpd.service`

Step 3: `systemctl start httpd.service`

Step 4: `firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=80/tcp`

Step 5: `firewall-cmd --reload`

After all this steps are done open your web browser and goto http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1

Your commands looks OK. But it's weird it's not recognizing systemctl.

Can I know the what is this system is. Is it a test RHEL setup ?

Comment: This system is RHEL, Thank you for your respond.

Comment: No, but the issue is we are using rhel 6.9 , and i got this result : [root@a0110tpocapp01 /]# systemctl enable httpd.service
bash: systemctl: command not found . Do you have any idea why?

Comment: As for my knowledge after RHEL 7 only it supports for systemctl. Try /etc/init.d httpd

Comment: As for my knowledge after RHEL 7 only it supports for systemctl. Try `chkconfig httpd` on (enable) and `/etc/init.d/httpd restart`

Comment: [root@a0110tpocapp01 appuser]# chkconfig httpd
[root@a0110tpocapp01 appuser]# /etc/init.d/httpd restart
Stopping httpd: [ OK ]
Starting httpd: [Thu Mar 30 10:09:02 2017] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
                                                           [ OK ]                                                        This the respond of the command that i have executed

Comment: You have not configured any virtual hosts. Open the browser in the server and go to http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1. Then you'll see the Apache welcome page.

Comment: Give me your email address. I'll send a video how the configuration done.

Comment: nmahirahaqilah.awahab@digi.com.my , thank you so much vinod, and i think this issue has something to do with the proxy server configuration,as this is my company's server.